# How to make a sentinel value become a valid value in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop, sentinel

One of the questions from my Java textbook is asking me to "Create a new version of the Average program (Listing 3.6) that prevents a runtime error when the user immediately enteres the sentinel value (without entering any valid values)."

Listing 3.6 is below:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int sum = 0, value, count = 0;
    double average;

    System.out.println ("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");
    value = scan.nextInt();


    while (value != 0) // sentinel value of 0 to terminate the loop
    {
        count++;
        sum += value;
        System.out.println ("The sum far is " + sum);

        System.out.print ("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");
        value = scan.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Number of values entered: " + count);

    average = (double)sum / count;

    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.###");

System.out.println ("The average is " + fmt.format(average));


}
}
```

I think what the question is asking is to make the sentinel value of 0 to be counted. Here is the output of Listing 3.6 when you type in the sentinel value.

Output:

```
Enter an integer (0 to quit): 
0

Number of values entered: 0
The average is �
```

Additionally, I think that instead of it saying `Number of values entered: 0`, I think it is suppose to say `Number of values entered: 1`. If you think you know what the question is asking, please let me know. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yor task contradicts to itself, since the code does not throw any exceptions if first input is 0. But it would throw if line _"average = (double)sum / count;"_ was _"average = sum / count;"_. So I suggest the task is wrong or it already contains the solution. However it is always better to ask the person who gave your this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a guard to make sure `count` is not equal to zero.

```
average = (double)sum / (count == 0 ? 1 : count);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because count doesn't get incremented until after you've checked the user's input. When the very first number is 0, the while loop is never entered and you end up dividing by 0.  The question is asking you to fix the code so that dividing by 0 is avoided and no exception is thrown.